# Safe way to access files outside /var/www

Tags: php, apache, file, security

Good day everyone,

I got a tricky question I can't figure out myself.

I made a webpage where people can upload different kind of files. Those files get renamed - the new filename is stored into a database - and moved to /home/myname/newfilename.xyz

So I focused on keeping those uploads as safe as possible and prevent myself of let people uploade "evil" files and execute em on some way.

I also made a kind of backend where I see all uploaded files - there I want to link the files so I can view/download em, but since they are not in the /var/www directory I can't access em by linking em like "../../../home/myname/newfilname.xyz". I know there are different ways to make a work-a-round, but before I do something, I want to know if someone knows the most safest way.

It would be great if someone in here can help me :)

Cheers

Comment: I would suggest a couple of oher things as well.  Limit the types of files the user can upload.  And set your server properties on the folder to read/write only, so they can't be executed.

Comment: Well its not a duplicate with the linked topic.
I have to keep write permissions so I can let my script uploade files to there right ? So I can't just go for "read" rights or do I get here something wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

One way to accomplish this, is to "stream" the files with PHP. You store the file reference in db, maybe you can reference the file by id instead of filename?

Let's say you create this PHP script:

```
http://mysite/downloadFile.php?fileId=1000
```

Then you can implement this by something like this:

```
$fileId = $_GET['fileId'];
$fileinfo = getfilenamefromdb($fileId); // fetch filename and mime type from db
if (!$fileinfo) die('File not found');

// access control?

header('Content-type: '.$fileinfo['mimetype']);
$content = file_get_contents('/home/myname/'.$fileinfo['filename']);
echo $content;
```

You'll have to implement `getfilenamefromdb()` function, and possibly access control. Referring by id will prevent someone from accessing your file system by asking for files like `../../../etc/passwd`

Comment: yea I have also Unique IDs which are my primary key.
your solution looks nice and seems logic - gonna test it and tell you how it went. :)

Comment: Great. You can access the mime type when the file is uploaded. Or else there are tons of file-extension-to-mime-type-libraries around.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.mime-content-type.php - helped me a lot on that topic

Thanks your help was a blessing!